# Android SDK Build Tools different versions in Android Studio and Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2017, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-manager, android-sdk-build-tools

I use Android Studio to build *native Android* projects and I installed the latest version of the Android SDK.

I also use Visual Studio to build *Xamarin.Android* projects. However when the build process runs in Visual Studio, it uses a previos version of the Build Tools.

I checked the SDK managers and found the following:

- Both manager uses the same SDK path (C:\Android\SDK)
- The latest Build Tools are installed (v28.0.3 as of time)
- Visual Studio can't find the latest version
- I already targeted API level 28 but it didn't help

Here you can see side-by-side the managers:

[image]

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Probably Xamarin needs to be updated as well as the SDK tools. Go for the stable version and update it. After a restart of VS it should be fine. Process explained [here](https://blog.xamarin.com/staying-date-visual-studio-2017-xamarin-updater/)

Comment: @UlugToprak Visual Studio is up to date and Xamarin is updated via the updates of the IDE. I highly doubt that after 6 months of the release of Android API level 28, Xamarin hasn't released the updated SDK manager.

Comment: You would be surprised... Android studio will look for an update on the SDK tool which is not supported by Xamarin yet. Build tools or something. Better keep the SDK's separate to avoid this situations